How to execute php script with a button (either with the shell command or with ajax)?
I'm a dev on the website archi-wiki.org. We have a weekly mail that is sent by the php function cli.php.
The shell command to run it manually is
php7.4 cli.php -g parentheses -api https://www.archi-wiki.org/api.php -t "Alerte mail hebdomadaire TEST" -u "aw2mw bot" -p '****************' -ns 4000,4006 -nsg 4000 --intro "MediaWiki:Alerte mail hebdomadaire" --target Aphfug -d

with '--target' the username of the person we want to send the mail to and '-t' the email object (those are the two arguments I want to let the user change).
The button to send the mail would be found here : Gestion alerte hebdo (it's the "envoyer mail test" button)
How can I get this button to run this script ? We can use node.js, jquery and ajax.
I tried with the execSync function but the import { execSync } from 'child_process'; fails to start the child_process. I tried const execSync = require('child_process').execSync; too.
I started the solution with AJAX and post method but I don't have the right to modify the cli.php for now (the main dev will give me the rights soon but I don't have them now)

You would normally execute PHP scripts as if they are web pages. That is, by using the web server, not the command line.

"I tried with the execSync function but the import { execSync } from 'child_process'; fails to start the child_process"
What does it return exactly ?

with const execSync = require('child_process').execSync; the exception is "Error: Module "child_process" is not loaded". And also, when I deploy it tells me "'const' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6') or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz)."
